# Пример для Clipboard.js работает на Codepen и Stack Overflow, но не локальном сервере или сайте

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

### Кратко

Хотелось бы добавить на страницы сайта кнопку, чтобы можно было быстро копировать куски кода. Поиск показывает, что легче всего задачу выполнить при помощи [**Clipboard.js**](https://clipboardjs.com/). Но не могу подключить данный скрипт, причём на Codepen.io и во встроенных сниппетах Stack Overflow тот же самый код работает, как надо.

---

---

### Минимальный пример кода

Дополнительно подключил только [**Rainbow**](https://craig.is/making/rainbows) для подсветки, чтобы желаемое поведение было визуально понятно.

```js
    new Clipboard('.SashaButton');
```

```css
    body {
        background: sienna;
        color: pink;
        margin: 0;
    }

    code {
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    .SashaButton {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.5rem;
        top: 0.5rem;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name=description content="">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.4.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://Kristinita.ru/bower-components/rainbow/dist/rainbow.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://Kristinita.ru/bower-components/rainbow/themes/css/espresso-libre.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Test code:</p>
    <pre class="SashaClipboard1"><code>Саша прекрасна!</code>&nbsp;<button class="SashaButton" data-clipboard-target=".SashaClipboard1"><img src="https://clipboardjs.com/assets/images/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard" width="13"></button></pre>
    <p>Example</p>
    <p>Another example code:</p>
    <pre class="SashaClipboard2"><code data-language="json">
        &quot;Sasha&quot;: &quot;never&quot;,
        &quot;forgive&quot;: &quot;me&quot;
        </code><button class="SashaButton" data-clipboard-target=".SashaClipboard2"><img src="https://clipboardjs.com/assets/images/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard" width="13"></button></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

---

---

### Желаемое поведение

**http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/bwzXqR**

[image: Желаемое поведение]

---

---

### Актуальное поведение

Код не работает как на сайте — **http://kristinita.ru/Sublime-Text/Test** — так и на локальном сервере. Тестировал на новейших версиях Firefox, Chrome и Opera.

Почему так происходит, не понял, дополнительных [**зависимостей**](https://clipboardjs.com/), согласно официальному сайту, устанавливать не требуется.

---

---

### Firebug

Firebug показывает ошибку:

```
TypeError: a is null
```

[image: Ошибка Firebug]

Разобраться дальше никак не получается.

---

---

### Вопросы

- Как правильно подключить Clipboard.js к сайту, чтобы получить желаемое поведение?
- Если объясните, почему код работает здесь и на Codepen.io, но не работает на сайте, будет неплохо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не смог воспроизвести Вашу проблему через `file://` и на локальном хосте.
`Chrome 53, FF 49`.

1. `<script src='/path/to/clipboard.js'></script>`.
   Но инициализировать нужно в стиле:
   `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => new Clipboard('.SashaButton'));`.
2. Из-за невозможности воспроизведения сказать, что не так, не представляется возможным.