# Перестал работать Clipboard is not defined

Tags: javascript, clipboard, clipboard.js

Здравствуйте. Использовал прекрасный скрипт Clipboard. Пару дней назад, не внося никаких изменений в скрипт, Clipboard  перестал работать.
Консоль выдает следующую ошибку: Clipboard is not defined

Подключаю следующим образом:

```
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"  async></script>
<script>
    new Clipboard('.btn-clipboard');
</script>
```

Вызываю так:

```
<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#cp-name">Copy</button>
```

Гуглил, пробовал разные варианты - рабочего решения не нашел. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. 
Спасибо!

Comment: А не может тут быть дело в `async`?

Comment: пробовал и без него. Результат не меняется.

Comment: @Waik, полностью не работающий участок кода могли бы привести? Чтобы отладку могли произвести потенциальные отвечающие. Включая то, как выглядит код с текстом, который Вы хотите скопировать. Как [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/582407/199934), например. На моём сайте нормально последняя версия Clipboard.js работает ([**тут много примеров**](https://kristinita.ru/IT-articles/How-to-publish-your-package-to-PyPI-2018)) Спасибо.

Comment: @Waik, скорее всего, Ваша проблема не в этом, но лучше всё же подключать внешние скрипты не посредством RawGit, а используя другие CDN. я, например, через JSDelivr подключаю: `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/latest/clipboard.min.js"></script>`. Причина — на jsDelivr и альтернативах Вы подключаете версии скрипта, включённые в релиз. Код, подключаемый посредством RawGit, может быть ещё не включён в релиз → больше вероятность, что он содержит ошибки. Спасибо.

Comment: Действительно, использовал CDN с вашего примера и это помогло! Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Помогла замена CDN на

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/latest/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```